# How to sum data from an annotated query

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm trying to create a report that shows the number of males, females, and total customers in a given day by hour.

The data is inserted into the database as a transaction whenever somebody enters the building. It stores their gender there.

The query to gather the data looks as follows:

```
initial_query = EventTransactions.objects.using('reportsdb')
                .filter(building_id=id, 
                        actualdatetime__lte=end_date, 
                        actualdatetime__gte=beg_date)
```

From there, I annotate the query to extract the date:

```
ordered_query = initial_query.annotate(
            year=ExtractYear('actualdatetime'),
            month=ExtractMonth('actualdatetime'),
            day=ExtractDay('actualdatetime'),
            hour=ExtractHour('actualdatetime'),
            male=Coalesce(Sum(Case(When(customer_gender='M', then=1)), output_field=IntegerField()), Value(0)),
            female=Coalesce(Sum(Case(When(customer_gender='F', then=1)), output_field=IntegerField()), Value(0))
            ).values(
            'year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'male', 'female'
            )
```

How do I then sum the male customers and female customers by hour?

By this, I mean that I wish to provide a table to the user which contains each hour of the day (can just be a number from 0-23 at this point), total males for that hour, total females for that hour, and total customers for that hour:

```
TIME | MALE | FEMALE | TOTAL
0      12     4        16
1      5      8        13
2      2      3        5
3      20     38       58
etc.
```

I'd be happy to provide more information if necessary. Thank you!

Comment: What would you like the output to look like, can you give an example?

Comment: @IainShelvington Sure thing, I just updated the question. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, and which DB are you using?

Comment: @IainShelvington PostgreSQL 9.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're nearly there. Do the annotation for the gendered populations after calling values such that the database will do the aggregate on the group of datetime extracted values.

```
ordered_query = initial_query.annotate(
                year=ExtractYear('actualdatetime'),
                month=ExtractMonth('actualdatetime'),
                day=ExtractDay('actualdatetime'),
                hour=ExtractHour('actualdatetime'),
            ).values(
                'year', 'month', 'day', 'hour',
            ).annotate(
                male=Coalesce(Sum(Case(When(customer_gender='M', then=1)), output_field=IntegerField()), Value(0)),
                female=Coalesce(Sum(Case(When(customer_gender='F', then=1)), output_field=IntegerField()), Value(0))
            )
```

Comment: Thank you! I (think) that worked. How would I then add the male and female columns together to get a sum of the whole hour?

Comment: Could you do `Sum(Value(1))`?